# "export PYTHONPATH = $PYTHONPATH:." in Windows Command Prompt

Tags: windows, set, export, command-prompt, pythonpath

This Linux command needs to be rewritten for Windows Command Prompt:

`export PYTHONPATH = $PYTHONPATH:.`

I have researched quite a bit already.

Please note:
**This is not necessarily about PYTHONPATH**, but about setting an environement variable from Windows command-line (Command Prompt) in an equivalent manner to the Linux code cited above.

Comment: something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-a-directory-to-the-path-environment-variable-in-windows

Comment: Could you please provide the exact command from there than?

Comment: I dont think even if you set env variable windows lets you use it you need a new terminal and all old ones will not know of new variable

Comment: It worked in the example I've seen:
Is that possibly because a virtual environment was being used in that example 
(instead of a plain Windows Command Prompt) ?

Comment: Better option is try asking this in https://superuser.com

Comment: Good advice. Thank you.